# How to solve InvalidClassException when reading an Object array in ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serializable, objectinputstream

I have to save and load a chess game. In Chess I have:

```
public class Chess 
{
private Piece[][] pieceArray;
private Board board;
private int moves;
private boolean turn;
...
Set's and get's
}
```

I would have to load the turn, moves and the matrix. For now Im only saving and loading the matrix (Pieces[][])

Now I have these methods for saving and loading the game in another class
In this class I have a FTPClient connected to a server.

Saving the game:

```
public boolean saveGame(Chess chess) {
    boolean error = false;
    try {

        File file = new File("game.save");
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
        oos.writeObject(chess.getArray());
        oos.close();

        // Save that file in the server
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("game.save"));
        client.storeFile("game.save", fis);

        fis.close();
        file.delete();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return error;
```

Saving the game gives me no problem and goes smoothly.

And now this is the method I use to load the game, which is the one throwing the invalidClassException.

```
try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("game.save"));
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            chess.setArray((Piece[][]) ois.readObject());
            chess.paintInBoard();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Whenever I try to read the matriz I get "java.io.InvalidClassException: [LPiece;; invalid descriptor for field "

I have implemented the Serializable interface in Piece and Chess. 
I have tried saving the whole Chess class but doing that I would have to implement the Serializable interface in other 8 classes as well and I'm trying to avoid that.
Do I have to read each Piece individually?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried saving the saves locally and it worked. The problem was that the server I was using corrupted the file every time I uploaded it, giving me that exception. Changing the server did the job.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to determine what the problem might be because the Piece interface nor its implementing classes are not provided, but here are my thoughts on this problem:

1. I personally would avoid saving an array or a matrix. I would instead save the pieces in a container class, for example: PieceCollection.
2. I can't see any specific problem with your provided code (unless chess.getArray() returns something else than pieceArray).
3. I believe that the main problem here is that the ObjectInputStream can't distinguish the various implementations of Piece. I would suggest that you try to add serialVersionUID to the implementing Piece classes. For more information, see the following link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html
4. The Piece classes are missing a no-arg constructor. See the following link for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/InvalidClassException.html

Good luck! I hope that this answer will help you.